# Rails Controller update subtract 1 from value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I subtract 1 from a value in a Rails Controller it's easy in Postgresql

```sql
 Update junkcars
 Set junkcartotal = junkcartotal -1
 Where id = 5161
```

In a rails controller I tried

```rb
Junkcars.update(junkcartotal: junkcartotal -1).where(id: 5161)
```

I get nothing but errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy in rails too:

```rb
Junkcar.find(5161).decrement!(:junkcartotal)
```

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-decrement-21*

Answer (score 0):

```
@junk_car = Junkcar.find(5161)
@junk_car.update(junkcartotal: @junk_car.junkcartotal - 1)
```

Comment: Watch out using calculations in the update method that also refers to itself as it might create a race condition where it updates to the same value twice. Use the `decrement!` method instead

Comment: Interesting, never come across this before. Do you have a link for this where I can read a little bit more about the technicalities of this?

Comment: Definetly: https://www.fastruby.io/blog/rails/code-quality/An-introduction-to-race-condition.html